# Retrieve a cookie with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I try to retrieve a certain cookie with Javascript and then use it for changing values in a form. However, I have a problem.

```
function retrieveCookie( cookieName ) {

    var cookieJar = document.cookie.split( "; " );
    for( var x = 0; x < cookieJar.length; x++ ) {
        var oneCookie = cookieJar[x].split( "=" );
        if( oneCookie[0] == escape( cookieName ) ) { return oneCookie[1] ? unescape( oneCookie[1] ) : ''; }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Cookie is always in this format `"name1=2catname2=10catname3=14"`

I want to retrieve it, split it in the word `cat` and keep the name and the value of each part.

```
form = retrieveCookie("nameofcookie");
alert(form)
```

But the alert shows `"name1` instead of the whole cookie value.

Comment: Do you have to support IE7? If not, go for localStorage.

Comment: Also, `str.split('cat')` ?

Comment: I prefer to support it, but I will move only if there isn't any other option. Can you provide a complete answer of how my code will change with localStorage?

Comment: It doesn't work since the returned cookie is only `"name1`...There isn't any `cat` inside